# Cannot deploy Spring Security SAML sample application correctly

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, spring-saml

I'm trying to deploy the sample application that's part of the Spring Security SAML extension, using SSOCircle as the IDP, but I've run into a number of problems. I'd really appreciate some help fixing this.

Here's what I've done.

I downloaded the source from: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/1.0.0.RELEASE and built the sample application via : `mvn package`. I then deployed the WAR file to a standalone instance of Tomcat (v7.0.41).

I launched the app: http://server:8550/spring-security-saml2-sample,
clicked on **Metadata Administration**, and clicked on the **Login** button, but I kept being redirecting back to http://server:8550/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/web/metadata/login.

I bypassed login for Metadata Administration by changing the line:

`<security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>`

in securityContext.xml to:

`<security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>`

Navigating back to http://server:8550/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/web/metadata, I could now click on the **Generate new service provider metadata** button. I entered a value for **Entity ID**, accepted defaults for the remaining options, and clicked **Generate metadata**.
I saved the SP metadata file to `/WEB-INF/classes/metadata/serverId_sp.xml` as instructed, and added the SP configuration data to `metadata` bean in `securityContext.xml`.
I logged in to https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso and registered SP metadata.
I then commented out both occurrences of the line:

`<security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>`

in `securityContext.xml`, and restarted the application.

On the main page I selected the http://idp.ssocircle.com option, and clicked **Start single sign-on**. I was correctly redirected to SSOCircle; I entered my user name & password, and was redirected back to the spring-security-saml2-sample application, but the following error was displayed:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:95)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a2ei6e3068d8fi72g4a0fcc1j41142
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:139)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
... 29 more
```

Regarding this specific problem, I don't think this answer ([Spring SAML integration with WSO2 Identity server, SAML Message ID not reconised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778889/spring-saml-integration-with-wso2-identity-server-saml-message-id-not-reconised)) is relevant, since I'm using SSOCircle as my IDP; i.e. the domains for my SP and the IDP are different.

The [section on troubleshooting](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/chapter-troubleshooting.html) in the Spring SAML documentation gives a way to disable checking the `InResponseToField` setting by modifying the `contextProvider` bean in `securityContext.xml`.
I implemented this fix, and restarted the test application once more.

I can log in via SSOCircle as before, but now when I'm redirected back to spring-security-saml2-sample, I'm always redirected back to http://server:8550/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/discovery?entityID=serverId&returnIDParam=idp; i.e. the details of the logged in user are not displayed (as in the online demo version at http://saml-federation.appspot.com/), and I never see the **Global Logout** and **Local Logout** buttons. Even if I enter the URL http://server:8550/spring-security-saml2-sample explicitly in my browser, I'm always redirected back to http://server:8550/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/discovery?entityID=serverId&returnIDParam=idp.

Since I'm deploying the sample application to a standalone instance of Tomcat, I also made the changes suggested in this answer: [Spring Security SAML Metadata URL on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212087/spring-security-saml-metadata-url-on-tomcat). However, the behaviour is still the same.

So, this is where I'm stuck now. Any ideas what might be causing my problems? Why isn't my version of the sample application behaving the same way as the online demo version?

Any help will be gratefully received - thank you.

**UPDATE**

The HAR file of the network traffic is here: http://pastebin.com/EUPHA4gE

The debug output to stdout is quite long; I've split it into two parts:

Part one: http://pastebin.com/TkZS7uZM

Part two: http://pastebin.com/mrRkLs2T

I've also posted the Tomcat access log if that's a help: http://pastebin.com/992btULh

**UPDATE 2**

The HAR file of the updated network traffic is here: http://pastebin.com/EUPHA4gE

The *original* war file I deployed (before making any of the changes mentioned above) is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18025575/spring-security-saml2-sample.war

A war file containing the configuration changes to various files, as described above, is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18025575/spring-security-saml2-sample-with-changes.war

Comment: Could you please record all traffic between your application and SSOCircle? Ideally by creating a HAR file as described here https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/, and adding the HAR as link to your question? Also, please enable debug logging as described in http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#logging and add the content.

Comment: Vladimír - many thanks for your help. I've created the logs, and added the output to pastebin. I've added the links to the original question.

Comment: Alan, I've been trying to find the problem, but failed so far. Could you please enhance the har file, so it also contains the first request to the Spring SAML application and the SSO login at SSOCircle? Could you upload the war you're deploying somewhere, so I could try to reproduce it?

Comment: Vladimír - thanks again for your continued help; sorry it's taken me a while to respond. I've updated the HAR file output, and uploaded two versions of the war file (before and after the configuration changes). Please see the original question for the links.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to go through it asap, but will be travelling for a week, so it may take a while.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The sample that is you are using, i have also used the same and its working properly. Only thing is you have to understand how Spring SAML works.

Its very simple. 
1. Deploy the sample application as a fresh project into tomcat.(Dont make any changes).

2.run the application and use the path (/saml/metadata) to download the default metadata.
  ex. if your server is localhost:8080/samlApplication
      then full path will be localhost:8080/samlApplication/saml/metadata
      note: samlApplication will be your application name.

3. copy and replace the content with the generated metadata XML content to /WEB-
   INF/classes/metadata/serverId_sp.xml.
4. Goto ssocircle and and register the metadata and make sure you are entering correct entity id, it will be in generated metadata like this entityID="your entitiy id".use the same.
5. Now run the application and login you will be properly redirected to main page with user detail.

your problem is in metadata. IDP use the SP metadata information to redirect the user back to SP so if you are having prob in redirection then definatly there is a prob in SP metadata.

AND can you post the metadata what you have generated so that it will be easy to check.

Here is the demo application i have used it.
follow the above instruction and try u will be sucess.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23694298/spring-saml-sso-sample.rar